# Update table dynamically with current currency conversion rates

Tags: php, html-table

**Edit**:

Well, I got it working thanks to jimmy's link. Here is the code I'm using to convert just in case someone else wants to try the same thing. This works best with a number you know is basically fixed or doesn't change often. Make sure you remove the notes as denoted by /// so you don't have floating text if you use the code below. Also note, the results are approximate so you might want to add a section that says as much. Liability stuff.

The code required to fetch the data from Google's API:

```
<?php

function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
$data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
$var = $data['0'];
return round($var,9); ///the 9 indicates how many decimal points you want. I set it at the API's limit of 9
}
?>

<?php ///turns the exchange rate into a php variable so we can use it later. 
$cad = currency("USD","CAD",1) ; ///The currency code converting from, the currency code converting to, and amount you want to convert. 
?> ///Best use 1 so for a simpler equation. (base amount * exchange rate = how much you'll need)

<?php 
$gbp = currency("USD","GBP",1) ; 
?>
```

The table with content:

```
<table border="1" style="margin-left: 35px; width:400px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left; width:190px"><strong>Currency</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>USD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>CAD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>GBP</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;">Conversion</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$5000</td> ///the base number I will be using to make the conversion.

<td style="text-align: center;">$<?php 
$basecad = $cad * 5000; ///multiply the base value (in this case $5000) by the conversion ratio stored in our php variable
$basecad = round($basecad, 0); ///rounds it up to 0 decimals for cleanliness
$basecad = number_format($basecad); ///formats it to have commas (1,000 vs 1000)
echo $basecad; ///prints result
?></td>

<td style="text-align: center;">$<?php  ///repeat as necessary for additional currencies or lines
$basegbp = $gbp * 5000;
$basegbp = round($basegbp, 0);
$basegbp = number_format($basegbp);
echo $basegbp;
?></span></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Original Question**

So, I had a strange and interesting idea for a company website I'm updating. The page details include currency exchange rates between a few different countries to help with trip planning. The idea I came up with is to update the exchange rates based on whatever the rate is when the page loads. The concept itself is similar to something I've done before but this time I have to use an iframe as generated by a third party. The iframe itself is basically just a currency table from http://themoneyconverter.com/WebTools.aspx. It outputs information into a table and each  includes an id for whatever currency rate it is. My question now is how can I extract the information from the iframe's  and turn it into a PHP variable I can use in the parent page. After that it's simple PHP calculations to output each expense result. The main problem comes from the fact I cannot modify the information in the iframe. I've delved the internet but cannot find anything but how to put PHP variables into an iframe, not take it out. Below is a sample of the iframe, namely the part I want to extract. Any help, either yes it's possible or no it's not, would be greatly appreciated.

The actual table I'm extracting it into is just an HTML table. I'll just be adding in a basic algorithm to convert the currency (i.e. $var1 x $iframecvar1) for each cell. If you need more info let me know and thanks ahead of time.

```
<table summary="Exchange Rates for Japanese Yen" id="major-currency-table">...
<td><div class="tmc i-USD"> </div></td> 
<td><a target="_blank" ,="" title="United States Dollar" href="/USD/Exchange_Rates_For_US_Dollar.aspx">USD</a></td> 
<td id="USD">0.01070</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how much you can alter the page you are working with or what that page looks like, I'd like to suggest an alternative to fetching the exchange rates from an iframe.

[This script](http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/) works quite well.

```
<?php
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
$amount = urlencode($amount);
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
$data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
$var = $data['0'];
return round($var,3);
}

echo currency("GBP","USD",1); 
?>
```

If this doesn't answer your problem, maybe it's of use to someone else.

Comment: You have solved my problem. This allowed me to make variables from the exchange rate inside the page rather than in an iframe which means I can create everything on one page. It's so very simple too. Thank you again good sir.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case the iframe is loading jQuery from Google and includes Google Analytics from themoneyconverter.com - so simply echoing this on your own page may cause undesired results.

That said, web scraping can get tricky, but here's a simple workflow - fetch the data in PHP and cast to a var with `file_get_contents` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://themoneyconverter.com/USD/RateTicker.aspx');
//echo the file
echo $file;
```

If you want to more sophisticated scraping of content I suggest Matthew Turland's blog or his book on the subject:

http://matthewturland.com/tag/web-scraping/

Comment: Hmm, I really have it as a hidden iframe and don't need to pull directly unless webscraping would be the only way. So, if I just had a table in an iframe, static, I could not pull it into the parent page using PHP?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how web requests work, and what an iframe actually is :)

Comment: I admit I'm no expert in any sort of coding whatsoever but I do not appreciate condescending statements. If you have something useful to add please do. If not then please do not comment. I know an iframe is an independent window just placed in a parent page and acts on its own. I have been able to pas information from a parent page to an iframe before with javascript hence why I'm asking if the other way around works and if I could do it in PHP.

Comment: Thank you phil, after a some more research into scraping I can see why you recommended it. I also now note that iFrames using a different DOM cannot be drawn from for security reasons. In effect, I cannot take the element out due to cross-site security whereas my ATS project was under the same DOM which allowed me to pass information along.